# Instant Upload and minimize the size on client side

Tags: php, jquery, wordpress, image

So, I have the following code for uploading an image:

```
<?php
if ($_FILES) {
  foreach ($_FILES as $file => $array) {
  $newupload = insert_attachment($file,$pid);
 }
}
?>
<div class="rh_image_upload">
    <input type="file" name="rh_image" id="rh_image" size="50">
</div>
<p align="right">
    <input type="submit" value="Publish" tabindex="6" id="submit" name="submit" />
</p>
<input type="hidden" name="post_type" id="post_type" value="post" />
<input type="hidden" name="action" value="post" />
<?php wp_nonce_field( 'new-post' ); ?>
```

and in the `functions.php`:

```
//Upload items
function insert_attachment($file_handler,$post_id,$setthumb='false') {
// check to make sure its a successful upload
if ($_FILES[$file_handler]['error'] !== UPLOAD_ERR_OK) __return_false();

require_once(ABSPATH . "wp-admin" . '/includes/image.php');
require_once(ABSPATH . "wp-admin" . '/includes/file.php');
require_once(ABSPATH . "wp-admin" . '/includes/media.php');

$attach_id = media_handle_upload( $file_handler, $post_id );

if ($setthumb) update_post_meta($post_id,'_thumbnail_id',$attach_id);
return $attach_id;
}
//Upload item done
```

**Problem:**

So the upload of the image does not happen till the submit button is clicked.
It is fine if the image size is small but with a large file size, it takes longer than acceptable.

1. So, is there a way to start the uploading process as soon as the image is selected (but not yet submitted)?
2. Also how do I limit the file type of "image" file only?
3. Lastly, is there a way to shrink the selected image size before the post is submitted?

Thanks guys!

Answer (score 0):

> 1. So, is there a way to start the uploading process as soon as the image is selected (but not yet submitted)?

Try utilizing `change` event , `$.post()` to upload user selected file to server

> 2. Also how do I limit the file type of "image" file only?

Set `accepts` attribute to `"image/*"` at `input` element

```
<input type="file" accepts="image/*" name="rh_image" id="rh_image" size="50">
```

> 3. Lastly, is there a way to shrink the selected image size before the post is submitted?

Create new `img` element , set `width` , `height` properties ? Use `canvas` element to return `data URI` of image after re-sized ?